# access value from nested object in php

Tags: php, arrays, object, nested

i have an object and i cant get the values :(

how in the world can i access the value "x" and "y" and get them into a variable?

this is crazy

var_dump shows me this:

```
object(Elliptic\EC\KeyPair)#1201 (2) {
  ["priv"]=>
  NULL
  ["pub"]=>
  object(Elliptic\Curve\ShortCurve\Point)#1206 (1) {
    ["EC Point"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["x"]=>
      string(64) "6f713d7037b148ad4027392aa5b27c575d3669f3691aba2a7cd91de5e616a448"
      ["y"]=>
      string(64) "34f4f38690796615e7bb70fb94cbc3db43d08a64bb9e5a24ac15afc92d148d8e"
    }
  }
}
```

print_r shows it like this

```
Elliptic\EC\KeyPair Object
(
    [priv] => 
    [pub] => Elliptic\Curve\ShortCurve\Point Object
        (
            [EC Point] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 6f713d7037b148ad4027392aa5b27c575d3669f3691aba2a7cd91de5e616a448
                    [y] => 34f4f38690796615e7bb70fb94cbc3db43d08a64bb9e5a24ac15afc92d148d8e
                )

        )

)
```

thanks for any directions.

Answer (score 0):

not that you think i am too lazy.
but i want the politically correct way to do this.

i found an ugly workaround, but it works for me:

```
$keysx=explode("[x] => ",$keys);$keysx=substr($keysx[1],0,64);
$keysy=explode("[y] => ",$keys);$keysy=substr($keysy[1],0,64);

echo "$keysx$keysy";
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's this:

```
$name_ofvariable_you_are_printing->pub['Ec Point']['x']
```

Comment: thanks for helping. well, this does not work. it does not output anything, instead it breaks execution of the script right there.
but it does not throw an error. its strange, so i went with my crippled text-parsing way.

Comment: if it helps use Kint to dump its a library and it might help you more in this scenario. if you search Kint php on google you can find it. Most probably there is an index of 0 [0] before one of the arrays. Another question.. are the objects public?